# Usage of LinkingObject

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, realm

I don't know how to use `LinkingObject` in below situation.

```
class Message: Object{
       ...
      dynamic fromUser : User?
      dynamic toUser : User?
}

class User: Object {
      ....
      let messages = List<Message>()
}
```

`messages` should has whole sent and received message.
How can I use LinkingObject?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Docs:

> With linking objects properties, you can obtain all objects that link to a given object from a specific property.

In your case I guess you want to get all linked `User`s in your `Message` instances, so you can define `LinkingObjects` like that:

```
class Message: Object {
      dynamic var fromUser : User?
      dynamic var toUser : User?

      let users = LinkingObjects(fromType: User.self, property: "messages")
}
```

Otherwise if you need to get all messages from or to user, you can use `LinkingObjects` this way:

```
class Message: Object {
    dynamic var fromUser : User?
    dynamic var toUser : User?
}

class User: Object {
    let fromMessages = LinkingObjects(fromType: Message.self, property: "fromUser")
    let toMessages = LinkingObjects(fromType: Message.self, property: "toUser")
}
```

`user.fromMessages` will contain all `Message`s with `fromUser == user`.

Please check out the [Relationships section in the Docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#relationships) for more info.

Comment: But I want to know this message's source user and target user. So I have made Message class to have 2 user property.

Comment: Thanks very much. It's good idea. But I have one problem. I need to sort messages by date, and how can I merge two message group into one sorted message group?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're going to achieve, but if you need to sort all messages by date, it easier to query all messages without using linking objects at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `LinkingObject` is used to tie an object to another object(s) so it could later easier to access. In your case, the User object later can easily called the Message object(s) related to that User.

So you can have the instance of User object and access it messages as below example.

```
let user = User()
// then get all messages to him
let messages = user.messages()
```

If you not have link, you need to manually do another query to get messages by user id or other property.

Comment: @MobileStar yes, if you dont have link / relationship. so the best practice should be using the link